# Возможно ли вывести изображение в консольном приложении на C#?

Tags: c#, консоль

Возможно ли сделать так, чтобы через консольное приложение можно было вывести изображение (jpg, например)? Если да, то как это сделать?

Comment: Разумеется, нет. Если только будете перегонять изображение в ASCII, но это совсем другое.

Comment: @PickNick: А куда вывести, простите? На консоль?

Comment: @PickNick, интересно просто, как вы себе это чудо представляете?
Наверное, единственным адекватным ответом будет ответ о конвертации изображения в ASCII-последовательность.

Comment: Естественно, можно! fbi. Также вроде можно более или менее простым образом катнуть битмап в /dev/fb0

Comment: @JacenKaedus какую связь вы видите между "/dev/fb0" и "c#"? :)

Comment: а вопрос точно с самого начала так назывался? может, я что-то пропустил

Answer (score 5):

Изображение символами:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Image Picture = Image.FromFile(@"1352.gif");
            Console.SetBufferSize((Picture.Width * 0x2), (Picture.Height * 0x2));
            FrameDimension Dimension = new FrameDimension(Picture.FrameDimensionsList[0x0]);
            int FrameCount = Picture.GetFrameCount(Dimension);
            int Left = Console.WindowLeft, Top = Console.WindowTop;
            char[] Chars = { '#', '#', '@', '%', '=', '+', '*', ':', '-', '.', ' ' };
            Picture.SelectActiveFrame(Dimension, 0x0);
            for (int i = 0x0; i < Picture.Height; i++)
            {
                for (int x = 0x0; x < Picture.Width; x++)
                {
                    Color Color = ((Bitmap)Picture).GetPixel(x, i);
                    int Gray = (Color.R + Color.G + Color.B) / 0x3;
                    int Index = (Gray * (Chars.Length - 0x1)) / 0xFF;
                    Console.Write(Chars[Index]);
                }
                Console.Write('\n');
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(Left, Top);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

https://gist.github.com/beliy26/c9ddbd33e5eaf94285e5